# Не может найти get_random_id в vk_api.utils

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Для отправки сообщения необходимо указать `random_id`, а получается он через `get_random_id`, однако найти его программа не может.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests

import vk_api
from vk_api import VkUpload
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id


def main():

    login, password = 'mail', 'pass'
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login, password)

    try:
        vk_session.auth(token_only=True)
    except vk_api.AuthError as error_msg:
        print(error_msg)
        return

    longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
    vk = vk_session.get_api()

    for event in longpoll.listen():

        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:
           if event.text == 'привет':
                if event.from_chat:
                    vk.messages.send(
                        user_id=event.user_id,
                        random_id=get_random_id(),
                        message='пока'
            )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Ошибка

> No name 'get_random_id' in module 'vk_api.utils'

Как это можно пофиксить или же чем можно заменить `get_random_id`?

Answer (score 1):

Для всех кто столкнулся с этой проблемой.
Обновите библиотеку vk_api до 11.4.0 через pip или же репозиторий.